# How to restrict user to specific stage of recruitment?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I want to add record level ***security*** in ***Applicant model***. I want to `restrict` `user` to specific stage of `recruitment process`, he can see only `stage` that is related to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed this `domain`

```
    [('name','=','First Interview')]
```

with object `hr.recruitment.stage` in `record rule`

Comment: That answer is bit short, hm? Plus, you can't restrict single users with that record rule, because record rules base on groups (every user a group can't be a solution). Instead i would define a field user_ids (many2many) on `hr.recruitment.stage` and use domain `[('user_ids', '=', user.id)]` on the record rule. That's a bit more flexible